# Throwing away a null error

Tags: javascript, null

In the code below I would like to throw away an error if a user puts null inside the parameter of the function.

```
function addSomething(array) {
    array=array.slice();
    if(array === null) {
    throw Error('Thrown away')
    }
    array.push('nah man');
    return array;
    };
    let myArray = [1, 2];
    addSomething(myArray);
    //=> [1, 2, 'nah man']
    addSomething(myArray);
    //=> [1, 2, 'nah man']
```

But I always end up with this error in the console.log when I try to call the function addSomething(null).

```
VM2829:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
        at addSomething (<anonymous>:6:11)
        at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Cannot read property 'push' of null? What? Why are they even connected with each other? All I want to do is to throw away an error. What am I doing wrong?
Note that I need to keep the array=array.slice() part so that I keep the function pure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do your defensive if (array === null) before calling array.slice

Comment: I get "Cannot read property '**slice**' of null" when I run your code which is exactly what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `null` before doing any operation on the `array` function argument, something like:

```
function addSomething(array) {
  if (!array) throw Error('Thrown away');
  array = array.slice();
  array.push('nah man');
  return array;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to check if it is actually an array instead for which you can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) but do it before you use any other array methods like slice or push

```
function addSomething(array) {
    if(!Array.isArray(array)){
       throw Error('Not an array');
    }
    array=array.slice();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you check if array is null after trying to use it

You would need to change your code to the following:

```
function addSomething(array) {
    //First check if array is null
    if(array === null) {
        throw Error('Thrown away')
    }
    //If this gets executed it means that the array is not null
    array=array.slice();
    array.push('nah man');
    return array;
};
```

One note though:

What's the point of `array = array.slice()`?This means that you assing a copy of `array` to `array` it self.Consider using indices in `slice()`

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot for the help, but what does "indices" mean?

Comment: @CodeSamurai it means indexes.Check this :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice